# Neo4J RelationShips MERGE ONCREATE ONMATCH

Tags: neo4j, cypher, oncreate, relationships

Is there a solution to distinct ON CREATE and ON MATCH on relationship MERGE ?

For example :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'http://ip/myfile.csv' AS row
MATCH (source:Ticket {Id: toInt(row.idticket)})
MATCH (target:User {Id: toInt(row.iduser)})
MERGE (source)-[rel:`AskBy` {}]->(target);
```

To do something like this

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'http://ip/myfile.csv' AS row
MATCH (source:Ticket {Id: toInt(row.idticket)})
MATCH (target:User {Id: toInt(row.iduser)})
MATCH (source)-[rel:`AskBy` {}]->(target);
ON CREATE SET (source)-[rel:`AskBy` {createDate: timespan()}]->(target)
ON MATCH SET (source)-[rel:`AskBy` {updateDate: timespan()}]->(target)
```

I want to distinct creation date and update date of relationship

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the property:

```
MATCH (source:Ticket {Id: toInt(row.idticket)})
MATCH (target:User {Id: toInt(row.iduser)})
MERGE (source)-[rel:AskBy]->(target)
ON CREATE SET rel.createDate = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET rel.updateDate = timestamp();
```

Comment: great ! is possible to also make a where condition on the MERGE ? For create relationship just on complexe condition ?

Comment: I have added an answer for your follow-on question. But @NicoleWhite's answer does answer your original question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the follow-on question in your comment to @NicoleWhite's correct answer:

1. `MERGE` does not allow any conditions. It will always create the specified pattern if it cannot match it.
2. Here is an example of how to achieve the equivalent of a "conditional MERGE" by using `OPTIONAL MATCH` and `FOREACH` as a workaround.

   This example pretends that this is the desired pseudo-logic:

   - If the `AskBy` relationship does not exist:

     - If the (make-believe) `source.priority` value is greater than 10, then create the relationship (with the `createDate` property)
     - Else do nothing
   - Else set its `updateDate` property.

     ```
     USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
     LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'http://ip/myfile.csv' AS row
     MATCH (source:Ticket {Id: toInt(row.idticket)})
     MATCH (target:User {Id: toInt(row.iduser)})
     OPTIONAL MATCH (source)-[rel:AskBy]->(target)
     WITH source, rel, target,
       (CASE
         WHEN rel IS NULL AND source.priority > 10 THEN {create: [1]}
         WHEN rel IS NULL THEN NULL
         ELSE {set: [1]}
       END) AS todo
     FOREACH (x IN todo.create | CREATE (source)-[rel:AskBy {createDate: timestamp()}]->(target))
     FOREACH (x IN todo.set | SET rel.updateDate = timestamp())
     ```